# What is the right and efficient way to retrieve data using Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have 2 tables:

```
T1
{
  Columns: **A**, B, C
}

T2
{
  Columns: D, E, F, **A**
}
```

`T1` has one to many connection to `T2` using a foreign key (column **A**).

I'm trying to retrieve a list of `F` in case that `A=1,B=2,E=3`.

What is the right and efficient way to retrieve this data?

- Is it join statement?
- Is it by retrieving all `T1 (where A=1,B=2)` including `T2` and then looping over the result (and eliminate the irrelevant `T2`)?
- Some other way?

Comment: Of course with single db query - using either manual join or navigation property, `where` clause and `select` **F**.

Comment: But in that way I retrieve many records that I don't use, and I need to loop over the results and remove the irrelevant records.

Comment: The `where` clause will do the filtering inside the database. `select` **F** will return only the data needed. This is optimal. No objects will be created. EF will use your model only as metadata for generating SQL query.

Answer (score 2):

```
var lst = (from t1 in context.T1
        join t2 in context.T2 on t1.A equals t2.A
        where t1.A == 1 && t1.B == 2 && t2.E == 3
        select t2.F).ToList();
```

- Join the tables
- Filter in the where clause
- Select just the one property you are interested in